# How can I get the colors in my photo to look like a painting by the Dutch masters?

Tags: post-processing, color, effect, painting

I am trying to make pictures look like paintings. I am interested about reaching a similar color grading.

This is an example: [link](http://1x.com/photo/275563/latest:all)

I'm asking an opinion about what kind of techniques should I use. It is not simply about saturation an vibrance. My opinion is that a more complex color grading process must be applied, but I cannot really get a similar effect.

I am not asking what should I do in PS or LR. Just conceptually, what would need to be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Matt Grum nicely proposed, warm tones are the key elements in the "soft painting" look of this beautiful photo. Indeed, if you *revert* the "bump" in reds and greens, the picture would look like *(with auto white balance and levels in photoshop)* :

[image: flat levels version]

If you look carefully, you can discover another element which contributes to the painting-like effect, for example let's take the details in the hand :

[image: hand details]

There is a nice job on lights here ! **The shadows are deep, but really soft.** I suspect the use of a large single softbox above the subject.
To give an opposite example, let's take a look on [this hand picture](http://500px.com/photo/33782025) with a very hard light, leading to high local contrasts, which non naturally emphases the details.
Finally, when trying *revert* this and thus to enhance local contrasts to revert this soft light, I got this more "usual" picture :

[image: enhance local details]

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually you need to boost the reds and greens to produce a very warm overall tone. There are dozens of ways to do this, the main ones would be:

- White balance during RAW conversion
- Colour balance tool in Photoshop
- Photo filter tool in Photoshop
- Curves tool in Photoshop